# Android : How to add child view on top of Softkeyboard for Emoji?

Tags: android, keyboard, emoji

I want to add a view with EmojiView on top of keyboard using EmojiView. Now I want functionality like when I onkey like primary code anything for EmojiView. I want to display a EmojiView on top of Softkeyboard. Means like adding pick from own view as subview of keyboard.

How can I do this?

Thanks for advance. Please share your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PopupWindow, it shows on top of Softkeyboard.
Look at https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

Comment: But i have this project but how to implements in IME.

Comment: did you try to use onKeyPreIme() from View class? with this one you can catch key presses

Answer (score 1):

Add library in your project and use following code:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
popupWindow = new EmojiconsPopup(popupView, getApplicationContext());
// final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow();
popupWindow.setSizeForSoftKeyboard();
popupWindow.setSize(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
popupWindow.showAtLocation(mInputView.getRootView(), Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

// Bring soft keyboard up : NOT WORKING
final InputMethodManager mInputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getBaseContext()
    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

mInputMethodManager.showSoftInput(popupView, 0);

// If the text keyboard closes, also dismiss the emoji popup
popupWindow.setOnSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener(new OnSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener() {

    @Override
    public void onKeyboardOpen(int keyBoardHeight) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyboardClose() {
        if (popupWindow.isShowing())
        popupWindow.dismiss();
    }
});

popupWindow.setOnEmojiconClickedListener(new OnEmojiconClickedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onEmojiconClicked(Emojicon emojicon) {
        mComposing.append(emojicon.getEmoji());
        commitTyped(getCurrentInputConnection());

        customToast("" + emojicon.getEmoji());
    }
});

popupWindow.setOnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener(new OnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onEmojiconBackspaceClicked(View v) {
        KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, 0, 0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL);
        customToast(" " + event);
        handleBackspace();
    }
});
```